# resize media player in android

Tags: android, media-player

I have been Created the app which contains default android media player with surfaceView. I can resize the Video , but not able to resize the media player for modify the height and with of play/pause button. In that I having 2 doubt.

1. Whether can I inflate any custom layout to replace that default media player.
2. Is it possible to convert MediaController to View or ViewGroup .
   or else, Is there any possibility to setLayoutParams() for mediaController in code not in xml?

Any have an idea?

Please help me!.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
ThiloG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your layout that will represent play, stop and pause (for instance) buttons. You just put it on your layout on the bottom. I didn't understand you very well, but this will do the work...